# If is good to definition Adapter or view in Activity

Tags: java, android

The following code style is Good?

```
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity{
    public ExampleAdapter extend BaseAdapter{
        //code here    
    }
    ExampleView extends View{
        //code here
    }
}
```

Comment: no its not a good style for coding.

Comment: Please tell me more .My colleague think the adapter can't reuse ,so he definition adapter in activity .

Comment: No its wrong. If you create custom outer adapter class then you need to use viewholder pattern which will optimize your listview.

Comment: This is a good point .But actually the adapter is extend PagerAdapter.

Comment: For `PagerAdapter` obvious you'r using view pager so you need to set `setOffscreenPageLimit()` for view pager which will be `1` by default to control how many pages are kept in memory and pre-created before being scrolled to. Also override the `destroyItem()` method in pager adapter class that will save the instance of your fragments/views and they won't need to load again and again

Comment: Thanks.We do have override the instantiateItem() and destroyItem() methods .I just confuse the code style.

Comment: As per name _instantiateItem_ your view will be instantiated after inflating custom row layout file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not good. It is considered a good practice to have an adapter as a stand-alone class (not nested one) as it will give you the benefit of **code reuse**.

Also, if you decide that you need a nested class anyway, make it `private`.

I recommend a book from Head First series: [Android Development](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920029045.do) to help you get basic perception for structuring your apps.

Comment: what if the adapter can't reuse?

Comment: Trust me, you **will** want to reuse your adapter sometime in the future. And moving your adapter from the `ExampleActivity` class is a good practice, even though you do not plan to reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

An adapter view, as its name suggests, is a View object. This means, you can add it to your activities the same way you add any other user interface widget. However, it is incapable of displaying any data on its own. Its contents are always determined by another object, an adapter. In this tutorial, I show you how to create adapters and use them to feed different types of adapter views such as ListView and GridView.